# How can I get tastypie to return related table data in the response

Tags: django-models, tastypie

I'm new to Django and I'm experimenting with using tastypie to create a simple API. I can't seem to figure out the proper way to show related information in one Resource from another.

Models.py

```
class TBucket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bucket_type = models.IntegerField()
    bucket_seed = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u't_bucket'
        ordering = ['name']

class TTransaction(models.Model):
    bucket = models.ForeignKey(Tbucket)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    amount = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    account = models.IntegerField()
```

api.py (snippet)

```
class BucketResource(ModelResource): 
    class Meta:
        queryset = TBucket.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'bucket'
        include_resource_uri = False
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','put','delete']
        authorization = Authorization()

class TransactionResource(ModelResource):
    bucket_name = fields.ToOneField(BucketResource, 'name', null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = TTransaction.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'transaction'
        include_resource_uri = False
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','put','delete']
        authorization= Authorization()
```

The records in the DB look like this:

```
t_bucket
id:1, name:Food, bucket_type:1, bucket_seed:50.00
id:2, name:Gas, bucket_type:1, bucket_seed:25.00

t_transaction:
id:5, bucket_id:1, date:2013-03-31, amount:8.75, account:1
id:6, bucket_id:2, date:2013-04-01, amount:25.50, account:1
```

When I hit the transaction URL, I see the following
    [{"id": 1, "bucket_name":null, "date":2013-03-31, "amount":8.75, "account":1},{...]

How can I get tastypie to do the lookup in the bucket table to get the "name" and return in the JSON response?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToOneField will display the whole BucketResource object, not only its name. It shows you null because you specified the attribute param to 'name', while it should be a field in the TTransaction model that point to TBucket model. In your case it will be following:

```
bucket = fields.ToOneField(BucketResource, 'bucket', null=True)
```

But as i said it will show you whole BucketResource. If you need only name from TBucket model you can override dehydrate method:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['bucket_name'] = bundle.obj.bucket.name
```

And it will show you only bucket_name this way